# Volley gives timeout Error but data is sent to server?

Tags: android

I am creating a chatting app using volley. When I send data to the server `onResponse` comes and I delete the particular thing from my senderHelper class so that it does not get sent again. Now the problem is that when volley timeout error occurs  `onErrorResponse` is called but the thing is that the data is on the server too.

Now the senderHelper is not cleaned and I cannot put my cleaning code in `onErrorResponse` because sometime the data may not be sent to server. So is there a way to know that even though timeout error occurs but data was sent to server?

```
public void emptySenderHelper(SenderHelper senderHelper) {
        if (senderHelper == null) {
            return;
        }
        String me = senderHelper.getSender_sh();
        String reciever = senderHelper.getReciever_sh();
        String msg = senderHelper.getMessageSent_sh();
        String img = senderHelper.getImageSent_sh();
        String encryptedAES = senderHelper.getAes_sh();
        String replySender = senderHelper.getReply_sender();
        String replyReciever = senderHelper.getReply_reciever();
        String replyToMessage = senderHelper.getReply_to_message();
        String replyToImage = senderHelper.getReply_to_image();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, sendMessageUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("success_sent")) {
                    chatViewModel.deleteSenderHelper(senderHelper);
                } else {
                    emptySenderHelper(senderHelper);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("from", me);
                params.put("to", reciever); // from is friend user name;
                params.put("msg_sent", msg);
                params.put("img_sent", img);
                params.put("encryptedAES", encryptedAES);
              /*  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());*/
                params.put("msg_date", senderHelper.getDate_sh());
              /*  simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                String time = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());*/
                params.put("msg_time", senderHelper.getTime_sh());

                params.put("reply_sender",replySender);
                params.put("reply_reciever",replyReciever);
                params.put("reply_to_message",replyToMessage);
                params.put("reply_to_image",replyToImage);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue myQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).getRequestQueue();
        myQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: The way i can think of is that on error response check for duplicate data on server but if a better way exist it would be great

Comment: kindly show error ..

Comment: @Adnanhaider The error is volley timeout. i have said that in question . There is no need to post error too

Answer (score 0):

It seems like i was posting too much data with volley. When i decreased some of the encryption its working normally now.